# How to clear toolwindow cache on exit visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a visual studio extension using c# that creates a toolwindow. The toolwindow still shows up after exit and reopen visual studio. Is there a way make sure the toolwindow does not show up on reopening visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **ProvideToolWindow** declaration you can set the **Transient** property to true to prevent the toolwindow from opening after VS restart:

```
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), Transient = true)]
```